# Excel VBA dictionary- How to get get Item values of Duplicate Key in cells?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, concatenation

Im trying to find way how to use Dictionary to delete duplicate values and concatenate items values in cells.

Code belowe is doing what i imagine but I can see it in immediate window (Debug.Print dict(People).

Item (ID) of duplicate values of dictionary Keys(People) are concatenate with comma but i dont know how to extract that Items to cell.

So idea for VBA to do is find duplicate value and concatenate ID values and delete duplicate.

Thank you!

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DictionaryTest()
    
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim People As String
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim item As Variant
    
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Debug.Print rowCount
    
    Do While rowCount > 1
    
        People = Sheet2.Cells(rowCount, "E").Value
        ID = Sheet2.Cells(rowCount, "D").Value
        
        If dict.Exists(People) Then
            'Sheet2.Rows(rowCount).EntireRow.Delete
            
        Else
            dict.Add People, ID
        End If
        
        rowCount = rowCount - 1
        
    Loop
 
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You did not match your real columns signification in your code and not fill the existing dictionary keys values... Please, test my answer code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this adapted code, please:

```
Sub DictionaryTest()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rowCount As Long, i As Long
    Dim People As String
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Set sh = Sheet2
    rowCount = sh.cells(Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To rowCount
        People = sh.cells(i, "D").Value
        ID = sh.cells(i, "C").Value
        
        If dict.Exists(People) Then
           dict(People) = dict(People) & "," & ID
        Else
            dict.Add People, ID
        End If
    Next i
    sh.Range("F2").Resize(dict.count).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Items)
    sh.Range("G2").Resize(dict.count).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.Keys)
End Sub
```

Comment: The code has been tested and it's excellent. I will need  study/research these functions (Resize, Transpose..) ,but it works. In this code if I want the value to be only in cells "C" and "D" like owerite and not in "F" and "G"  just i need to change sh.Range("F2") ..("G2") to "C" and "D"  trought loop. Im i understand it correctly?

Comment: @Mato Mišić . Glad I could help! Resize is used when an array must be dropped. The range must be adapted to the array dimensions. In this specific case, the `dict.Count` returns the dictionary elements number. And dictionary.Keys or dictionary.Items are 1 D arrays. In order to fill a column (like in our case) they must be transposed... And, yes, the cell to be resized to drop the dictionary elements can be defined as you suggested.

Comment: @Mato Mišić: But we here, when somebody spends some time and post a piece of code able to solve our problem, vote the code up, if enough notoriety and more important, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works... :)

Comment: I can do some stuff with it... Awesome code!  Thank you so much! !